# Quotients of the maximal tensor product

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be C*-algebras and let $\gamma$ be any C*-norm on the algebraic tensor product $A\odot B$. Why is $A\otimes_\gamma B$ a quotient of $A\otimes_{{\rm max}}B$, where $\otimes_{{\rm max}}$ stands for the maximal tensor product of C*-algebras? How does this quotient map look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition of the max norm, you have
$$
\|x\|_\gamma\leq\|x\|_\max
$$
for all $x$ in $A\odot B$. This tells you that the identity map $A\odot B\to A\odot B$ is a continuous function when you consider $\|\cdot\|_\max$ in the domain, and $\|\cdot\|_\gamma$ in the codomain. This map, call it $\pi$, can be extended to the completion, since given a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ we have 
$$
\|\pi x_n-\pi x_m\|=\|\pi(x_n-x_m)\|\leq \|\pi\|\,\|x_n-x_m\|,
$$
so $\{\pi(x_n)\}$ is also Cauchy. The extension $\pi$ is also a $*$-homomorphism, since it is on a dense subset of $A\otimes_\max B$. So we have obtained a canonical $*$-homomorphism
$$
\pi:A\otimes_\max B\to A\otimes_\gamma B.
$$
By the First Isomorphism Theorem, $A\otimes_\gamma B$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $A\otimes_\max B$ (namely, its quotient by the kernel of $\pi$).

An explicit form of the quotient map would require having explicit forms of the completions $A\otimes_\max B$ and $A\otimes_\gamma B$ of $A\odot B$. I don't think such a thing exists in any meaninful example, and it is what it makes dealing with tensor products an art.

Comment: How to show that $\pi:A\otimes_\max B\to A\otimes_\gamma B$ is surjective?.

Comment: Once you look at the quotient map onto the image, you get an injective C$^*$-homomorphism, and these are isometric. It is easy to show that the image of a closed set by an isometry is closed. So now the image is dense and closed, thus everything.

Comment: Why $ \pi(A\otimes_\max B)$ is dense in $ A\otimes_\gamma B$?

Comment: Because the image contains $A\odot B$, and $A\otimes_\gamma B$ is *define* as the completion of $A\odot B$.

Comment: Is the extension $\bar{\pi}$ of $\pi$ a injective * homomorphism?

Comment: If $\bar\pi$ is injective, it is isometric, which implies that $\|\cdot\|_\gamma=\|\cdot\|_\max$.

Comment: What do you mean by saying"you get a injective * homomorphism"?

Comment: What I meant is that you can (always, this is basic algebra) define $\tilde\pi:A\otimes_\max B/\ker \pi$ by $\tilde\pi(x+\ker\pi)=\pi(x)$. This map is always injective, since its kernel is $\ker\pi$ which is the zero in the quotient.

Comment: Very clear.Thanks,Pro Argerami.